# How to make texbox to null after I got success in jQuery AJAX method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am strangling when I added my comments with AJAX method of jQuery, after stressful, I want to make this textbox to null

my Ajax method like this :

```
function AddComments() {
            $(".Comment input[type=text]").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var comment = $("#" + this.id).val();
                    var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("txt", "div");
                    $(textId).append(comment);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Posts.aspx/AddComments",
                        data: "{'id': '" + this.id.replace("txt", "") + "','comments': '" + comment + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#" + this.id).val("");
                            //alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

what I want is on Success, I want make current textbox to NULL

```
$("#" + this.id).val("");
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `$(this)` instead of `$("#" + this.id)`, shouldn't you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. `this` in the `success` handler holds a reference to the `window` object, not the `input` the `keypress` fired on. You just need to cache the `input` in a variable you can use in the `success` handler. Try this:

```
function AddComments() {
    $(".Comment input[type=text]").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var $input = $(this);
            var comment = $input.val();
            var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("txt", "div");

            $(textId).append(comment);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Posts.aspx/AddComments",
                data: "{'id': '" + this.id.replace("txt", "") + "','comments': '" + comment + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $input.val("");
                    //alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access this in jquery ajax do it like this save your object in any variable

```
function AddComments() {
            $(".Comment input[type=text]").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var Element=this;
                    var comment = $("#" + this.id).val();
                    var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("txt", "div");
                    $(textId).append(comment);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Posts.aspx/AddComments",
                        data: "{'id': '" + this.id.replace("txt", "") + "','comments': '" + comment + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $(Element).val("");
                            //alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: you shouldn't use a variable, ajax calls are asynchronous and you can't be sure if the variable have the value that you excpect

Comment: @arieljuod so how can we access the value?

Comment: check my answer below, the ajax call sends the ID to the controller, it builds the json response and send back, also, that same id, then the id is accessible via the json data, that way you are sure that the id is the id you are expecting

Answer (score -1):

Your success function is in another context, you can't use this, you have to send the id on the json response and do something like:

```
success: function (response) {
  $('#'+response.div_id).val("");
}
```

and your json response should include the div_id that's passed on the ajax request